# c# SelectNodes with XPath ignoring cases in content of tag HTML

Tags: c#, html, xpath

i have a problem with my project. i got HTML from a website,then i want to SelectSingleNode with xpath, this is content html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<h3 class="bp">Groups you are in</h3>
</div> </body> </html>
```

and this is my code:

```
var xpath = string.Format("//html/body/div/h3[.= '{0}'","groups you are in")
var header = BuildDom("{this is link website i get html}").SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

this is my class BuildDom:

```
HtmlNode BuildDom(string url)
{
    string htmlContent = _http.DownloadContent(url);
    return HtmlHelper.BuildDom(htmlContent);
}
```

plz look at:

```
var header = BuildDom("{this is link website i get html}").SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

header will be null; because in html tag h3: **Groups you are in**

and in my xpath: **"groups you are in"**

how can i use with xpath "group you are in"? ignoring cases in tag h3 from html.
i cant change my xpath to "Groups you are in" because in html, sometimes h3 content "groups you are in", sometimes content "Groups you are in", or "Group You Are In"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `matches()`. Flag `"i"` allow to ignore cases

```
//html/body/div/h3[matches(., "groups you are in", "i")]
```

Comment: u mean:

      var xpath = string.Format("//html/body/div/h3[matches(., "groups you are in", "i")]= '{0}'","groups you are in")?????

Comment: I'm not sure about syntax correctness, as I'm not much familiar with `C#`, but try `string.Format("//html/body/div/h3[matches(., '{0}', 'i')] ","groups you are in")`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is, that you match against lower, or upper case.

```
"//html/body/div/h3[lower-case(.) = 'groups you are in']"
```

Comment: Important note: lower-case is only available in XSLT 2.0. If you use 1.0 you can use the following workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976570/xpath-lower-case-function